# How to specify path of files in resources when reading the content in Java

Tags: java, resources, inputstream

I have a txt file in resources folder. Structure looks as:

```
src -> main -> java

            -> resources -> document.txt
```

I need to read the content of text file. For that I tried following snippet:

```
InputStream inputStream = ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/document.txt");
```

and

```
InputStream inputStream = ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("document.txt");
```

and

```
InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("document.txt");
```

In all instances, inputStream becomes `null`, what is the correct way of specifying path or reading file content from resources

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

> BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
>   InputStreamReader(Classname.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename.txt")));

Answer (score 1):

Use this method:

```
InputStream inputStream = ClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("document.txt");
```

Comment: No, folder structure is correct. Resource folder should have the following structure src/main/resources

Comment: @NikitaMantri you are right, I've edited the answer with just the method that works for me.